# cannot properly import the chatterbot and its corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot, python-install

I have used:

```
|
+ -  lib
|     |
|     + - chatterbot
|     |
|     + - chatterbot_corpus
+ -  main.py
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.chatterbot.chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "D:\Workspace\PYTHON\phraser\lib\chatterbot\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "D:\Workspace\PYTHON\phraser\lib\chatterbot\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .storage import StorageAdapter
  File "D:\Workspace\PYTHON\phraser\lib\chatterbot\chatterbot\storage\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .django_storage import DjangoStorageAdapter
  File "D:\Workspace\PYTHON\phraser\lib\chatterbot\chatterbot\storage\django_storage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'
```

How can I solve this?

I don't want to install the module in python.

Comment: where is `__init__.py` files ? read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: @zimdero ref:https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git in addition i have added in lib folder for accessing it in main.py

Answer (score 5):

For error, `No module named 'chatterbot'` install chatterbot by running

```
pip install chatterbot
```

For more info click [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/)

For error, `No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'` install chatterbot_corpus by running

```
pip install chatterbot-corpus
```

For more info click [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/chatterbot-corpus/)

Answer (score 2):

do this first

> pip install --ignore-installed PyYAML

then do this

> pip install chatterbot_corpus

for devs on windows

Answer (score 1):

try to install throw pip [install docs](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html)

```
pip install chatterbot
```

create a new python file module, for example `main.py`, and import chatterbot, [example docs](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html)

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
```

i run this and it works, try

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i need to change the some files in chatterbot i dont want to install it every time!

Comment: oh i don't know that you want to change something, i think you cant install it

Comment: for python 3 try ```pip3 install chatterbot``` , ```pip3 install chatterbot-corpus```

Answer (score 1):

## for chatterbot install  on ubuntu python3

pip3 install chatterbot

pip3 install chatterbot-corpus

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
pip install --user chatterbot
```

Answer (score 0):

To install chatterbot you can simply fire the command.

> pip install chatterbot

After installing chatterbot you should install chatterbot-coprus.

> pip install chatterbot-coprus

If above command does not work.
Then try bellow.
I did struggle a lot. I tried with python 3.7 and 3.6 , I was facing the same issue.
finally i manually download and pasted in the C:\Python\python36\Lib\site-packages
and it worked .
make sure you put your python path correctly.

Comment: for python 3 try ```pip3 install chatterbot``` , ```pip3 install chatterbot-corpus```